# Why isn't this a violation of the one-definition rule?

Tags: c++, struct

Minimal example I can come up with:

headertest.hpp:

```
struct Point 
{
    int y;
};
```

structtest.cpp:

```
#include "headertest.hpp"

class myClass 
{
    public:
    private:

        struct Point 
        {
            double x;
        };

        Point myPoint;
};
```

On my machine (GCC 9.2.0 for MinGW) this compiles perfectly fine with no complaints. I can remove either the header or the definition in the class and it will work, so long as at least one is present.

The two different structs can have all the same members, or all totally different members, it does not seem to matter.

Why does this seem to work? Would it only be caught at run-time, or have I missed something very significant?

Comment: one is `Point `. The other is `myClass::Point`. Different things.

Comment: Then how is it decided which one will be used? Does it just go by which is the last one found? Or are internal ones preferred to ones from a header?

Comment: Close. It's generally decided by the narrowest scope. If you want to see the gory details for yourself, give the name look-up link R Sahu provided a read through.

Comment: > *Then how is it decided which one will be used?*  Name resolution, relative to a scope and lookup rules. In the class scope of `myClass`, unqualified `Point` refers to `myClass::Point`. If you want the file scope one, you must qualify it as `::Point`.   The class scope of `myClass` encompasses the interior of the class declartion, as well as the interior of member functions, even if they are defined outside of the class declaration. In all those places, `Point` is `myClass::Point`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The struct in the hpp file is in the global scope, while the one in the cpp file exists in the myClass scope only (`myClass::Point`).

If you instantiate a variable of the type `Point` from within the scope of myClass, the local definition will be used. This problem is similar to [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing), except that we are dealing with type names here instead of variable names.

Comment: Then which is used in the class when I do ```Point myPoint;```? Does it default to class scope before going out to global scope?

Comment: Yes, it does. I added some information to my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: It's not variable shadowing. There are no variables here. It's type name shadowing but I am not sure that is an accepted term. The standard puts them under [Name lookup](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.lookup).